# Get MAC of LAN-adapters, not of WLAN in Qt 4.8

Tags: c++, qt4, mac-address

I whant to use MAC as machine identifier in Qt-app (Win 7, C++)
If I obtain QNetworkInterface list with QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces(), there are too many WLAN network adapters, which are not even used. As I found out, they are left by not well-programmed drivers.

Is there a way to detect if the inteface is an Ethernet-LAN or Wireles-LAN?
The QNetworkInterface doesn't provide any information concerning the interface type.